# Polynomial Ring Explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

1. Consider the below polynomial ring
   $$\mathbb Z[X]/(X^4 + 1)$$

I think the above is a quotient ring,
and because $X^4 + 1$ can't be further factorized under $Z$,
the above ring consists of all the polynomials of degree $<4$,
whose coefficients are integers.
Is my reasoning for the above statement right?

2. Consider the below polynomial ring
   $$\mathbb Z_{17}[X]/(X^4 + 1)$$

Although $X^4 + 1$ can't be further factorized under $Z$,
I think it doesn't hold true
considering we are under $Z_{17}$ now.
Consider the following,
$$\mathbb (X^2 + 4)(X^2 - 4) = X^4 - 16 = X^4 + 1$$
because of $Z_{17}$. So that means that $X^4 + 1$ can be factorized under $Z_{17}$, right?

3. Continuing the above polynomial ring
   $$\mathbb Z_{17}[X]/(X^4 + 1)$$

Since $X^4 + 1$ can be factorized into $(X^2 + 4)(X^2 - 4)$,
what elements are in the ring now?
Is it still polynomials of degree $<4$ according to Q1?
Or is it polynomials of degree $<2$ because of $(X^2 + 4)$ and $(X^2 - 4)$?

Thanks!

Comment: $\Bbb Z[X]/(X^4+1)$ cannot be embedded as a ring in $\Bbb Z[X]$, so it's a bit unclear what you mean by it consisting of polynomials with of degree $<4$ with integer coefficients. $\Bbb Z[X]/(X^4+1)$ is a free $\Bbb Z$-module with basis $1,X, X^2, X^3$, but that would be true even if you were quotienting by a reducible polynomial, as long as it's monic of degree $4$.

Comment: I was looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring, so to my understanding, $\mathbb R[X]/(X^4 + 1)$ is a ring in $R[X]$ but not for $Z$, right?

Comment: No, a quotient $R[x]/(f(x))$ is not a subset of $R[x]$ if $f$ is nontrivial.

Comment: @fuo55631 If you replace every occurrence of $\Bbb Z$ with $\Bbb R$ and "integer" with "real" in my previous statement you obtain an equally true statement. The instances when a quotient ring $A/I$ embeds as a subring in $A$ are very rare and often uninteresting.

Comment: Got it. I need some time to understand it further, Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Over the finite field $\Bbb F_{17}$ we have
$$
x^4+1=(x + 15)(x + 9)(x + 8)(x + 2).
$$
Therefore the quotient has zero divisors and looks different from what you have over $\Bbb Z$, where it is a field. Still, the classes consist of polynomials of degree $\le 3$.

Comment: Does it means that the ring contains only constant terms (degrees of < 1) because it can be factorized into (x+15)(x+9)(x+8)(x+2), Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395028/how-to-deal-with-polynomial-quotient-rings) by A. Caranti, which is very similar to your case, namely $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^4+1)$. The (classes of) polynomials are still of degree $\le 3$ in the quotient, but a nontrivial product can be zero.

Comment: I see. But I got confused with the following answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200710/determining-the-ideals-of-a-quotient-ring. In that question it says that because x^3 - x can be factored into x(x + 1)(x - 1), so the ring will consists only constant terms, what makes the differences between this two questions, Thanks!

Comment: No, this is no difference. You just write the quotient as a direct product of quotients using the CRT. This doesn't change what $K[x]/f(x))$ is by definition. It only shows that it is isomorphic to a direct product of fields.

Comment: I somewhat got the idea. The main idea I was originally think was [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_learning_with_errors#Background), where it choose an irreducible polynomial phi(x), and a prime number q, I originally thought that it chooses phi(x) because it is irreducible, but to my surprise if it is reducible under Z_q, then what are the advantages of choosing an irreducible polynomial phi(x) at the first place, Thanks!

Comment: I would like to point out that the irreducible polynomial phi(x) in the above comment are often chosen as a [Cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), which X^4 + 1 is, hence the problem, Thanks!